# Use of default constructor of Object class in java

Tags: java, constructor

When you write `Dog d = new Dog();`
the default constructor of `Dog` class will be called. First line of default constructor of `Dog` class will be `super()` which will call default constructor of `Object` class. What does this mean? It will create two object, one object of `Dog` class and one object of `Object` class?

If you say it will only create object of `Dog` class then what will be effect of default constructor of `Object` class which will be called from default constructor of `Dog` class?

Comment: A constructor does not create an instance. It initializes it. Also, don't confuse default constructor with parameterless constructor.

Comment: Even Object has some stuff that needs initializing. See the javadoc for java.lang.Object to get an idea.

Comment: A constructor is used to initialize the member variables not create an instance. When you call super, it calls the default constructor of object to initialize members not create an object of Object class

Comment: @laune i did check javadoc. Nothing mentioned as such :(

Comment: What confusion do you still have?

Comment: What's effect of default constructor of Object class while creating object of any class?

Comment: More details on the default constructor [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9).

Comment: There is the reference to the object's class.

Comment: I dont think default constructor has any use but thats the language specs. If a class has no constructor, compiler providers a default constructor which by default will call the superclass no arg constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try explaining why this is; When you initialize a "dog", you have to think about what that dog is. What are you really doing here? Well, first, if the dog class extends anything, you must also initialize something of that type. For example, let's say dog extends animal. How can you initialize a dog without initializing an animal? All dogs are animals, so to initialize a dog you call `super()` to initialize the animal as well. This chain of events can be followed all the way up to the initialization of an Object; after all, **all objects** in java extend `Object`. It follows that you cannot have a dog without having an animal first; you cannot have an animal without having an organism first; etc etc etc, you cannot have an ___ without having an Object first; This is why java uses the default constructor for Object. 1)  You **MUST** have an object, and 2) there is no provided constructor in the Object source code.

Keep in mind that the default constructor will only be used if you did not provide a constructor. If you wrote

```
public Dog() { 
    //code
}  // this is just a no param constructor
```

in your code, you won't be given the default constructor. In java, the default constructor will only be given to you if you did not define one.

Comment: I completely agree with you but my doubt is what's effect of default constructor of Object class while creating object. What is initialization of an Object?

Comment: Do you mean you want the code for what's in the object constructor?

Comment: sorry.. i understand initialization i don't want any code.

Comment: Then what is the question here?

Comment: What is use of default constructor of Object class while creating object of any class since constructor of any class will always call default constructor of object class?

Comment: It's a logical thing. You cannot have a dog without having an animal first; you cannot have an animal without having an organism first; etc etc etc, you cannot have an ___ without having an Object first; This is why java uses the default constructor for Object. 1) You MUST have an object, and 2) there is no provided constructor in the Object source code. Since reason 1) and 2), java will do it for you.

Comment: Thanks everyone.. i think i got it. Thanks @Aify for helping me to clear my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - the default constructor is a constructor supplied by the compiler for you in case you do not want to write it. If you write one constructor, then that one will be used (not default constructor).

Now back to your question, you only create one object in the constructor. That object will have some variables that will be initialized in the order they are defined. First you will initialize the super class members and then your Dog class members. This is what super() means.